# Domain change - So how to update google properties?

Tags: ads, google-search-console, google-analytics-4

Recently one of my clients changes the domain name and I am facing some issues with changing the new domain in Google tools like search console and Analytics GA4 and AdWords.

Option 1 : Go ahead and create new properties all for a new domain.
Option 2 : While switching domains they have the same code at the backend so in GA4 there is the same code it is processing. I am getting data. So should I keep it as it is or should I need to create a new property?